# JS code effects not reflecting on the portfolio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am writing a HTML,CSS,JS code for a portfolio 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2Uxg.png)
I have reviewed my js and html code and I believe they do not have any error

I have included the necessary references for css and js external files in the html file
but the js code does not work nor does it give any error

The js code here is responsible to fill the circle/skill bar outline as per the data-percent

I am a beginner and I believe there is a very silly error which I am not able to resolve

HTML CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="project2.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="project2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Resume</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">




</head>


<div class="resume">
    <div class="base">
        <div class="profile">
            <div class="photo">
                <!--<img src="" /> -->

            </div>
            <div class="info">
                <img src="unnamed.png" height="100" width="100">
                <h1 class="name">Japnit Singh</h1>
                <h2 class="job">Software developer Coop</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="about">
            <h3>About Me</h3>I'm a web designer for Fiserv, specializing in web design, graphic design, and UX.
            Experienced with the Adobe Creative Suite, responsive design, social media management, and prototyping.
        </div>
        <div class="contact">
            <h3>Contact Me</h3>
            <div class="call"><a href="tel:2899-255-802"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><span>2899255802</span></a></div>
            <div class="address"><a
                    href="https://www.google.ca/maps/place/1280+Main+St+W,+Hamilton,+ON+L8S+4L8/@43.2618377,-79.9224208,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x882c84ad20954fad:0x28443fc4bf4d1fe!8m2!3d43.2618377!4d-79.9202321"><i
                        class="fa fa-map-marker"></i><span>McMaster<br> University</span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="email"><a href="mailto:singj36@mcmaster.ca"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><span>Japnit's
                        Email</span></a></div>
            <div class="email"><a href="mailto:singj36@mcmaster.ca"><i class="fa fa-print"></i><span>Japnit's
                        Resume</span></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="follow">
            <h3>Follow Me</h3>
            <div class="box">
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/japnit.singh.583" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/japnit-singh-41788a157/" target="_blank"><i
                        class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                <a href="https://github.com/JapnitS" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="func">
        <div class="work">
            <h3><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>Experience</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><span>Technical Consultant -<br>Web Design</span><small>Fiserv</small><small>Apr 2018 - Now</small>
                </li>
                <li><span>Web Designer</span><small>Lynden</small><small>Jan 2018 - Apr 2018</small></li>
                <li><span>Intern - Web Design</span><small>Lynden</small><small>Aug 2017 - Dec 2017</small></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="edu">
            <h3><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i>Education</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><span>Bachelor of Science<br>Web Design and Development</span><small>BYU-Idaho</small><small>Jan.
                        2016 - Apr. 2018</small></li>
                <li><span>Computer Science</span><small>Edmonds Community College</small><small>Sept. 2014 - Dec.
                        2015</small></li>
                <li><span>High School</span><small>Henry M. Jackson High School</small><small>Jan. 2013 - Jun.
                        2015</small></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="skills-prog">
            <h3><i class="fa fa-code"></i>Programming Skills</h3>
            <ul>
                <li data-percent="100"><span>Python</span>
                    <div class="skills-bar">
                        <div class="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li data-percent="90"><span>C++(OOP)</span>
                    <div class="skills-bar">
                        <div class="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li data-percent="60"><span>JavaScript</span>
                    <div class="skills-bar">
                        <div class="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li data-percent="50"><span>MySQL</span>
                    <div class="skills-bar">
                        <div class="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li data-percent="40"><span>JSON</span>
                    <div class="skills-bar">
                        <div class="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li data-percent="55"><span>Django</span>
                    <div class="skills-bar">
                        <div class="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li data-percent="40"><span>MySQL</span>
                    <div class="skills-bar">
                        <div class="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li data-percent="80"><span>Bash</span>
                    <div class="skills-bar">
                        <div class="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="skills-soft">
            <h3><i class="fa fa-laptop-code"></i>Software Skills</h3>
            <ul>
                <li data-percent="90">
                    <svg viewbox="0 0 100 100">
                        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45"></circle>
                        <circle class="cbar" cx="50" cy="50" r="45"></circle>
                    </svg><span>Git</span><small>90%</small>
                </li>
                <li data-percent="75">
                    <svg viewbox="0 0 100 100">
                        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45"></circle>
                        <circle class="cbar" cx="50" cy="50" r="45"></circle>
                    </svg><span>Node.js</span><small>75%</small>
                </li>
                <li data-percent="85">
                    <svg viewbox="0 0 100 100">
                        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45"></circle>
                        <circle class="cbar" cx="50" cy="50" r="45"></circle>
                    </svg><span>React.js</span><small>85%</small>
                </li>
                <li data-percent="65">
                    <svg viewbox="0 0 100 100">
                        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45"></circle>
                        <circle class="cbar" cx="50" cy="50" r="45"></circle>
                    </svg><span>Adobe XD</span><small>65%</small>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="interests">
            <h3><i class="fa fa-star"></i>Interests</h3>
            <div class="interests-items">
                <div class="art"><i class="fa fa-artstation"></i><span>Art</span></div>
                <div class="art"><i class="fa fa-book"></i><span>Books</span></div>
                <div class="movies"><i class="fa fa-film"></i><span>Movies</span></div>
                <div class="music"><i class="fa fa-headphones"></i><span>Music</span></div>
                <div class="games"><i class="fa fa-gamepad"></i><span>Games</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



</html>
```

JS CODE :

```
    $(".skills-prog li")
        .find(".skills-bar")
        .each(function (i) {
            $(this)
                .find(".bar")
                .delay(i * 150)
                .animate({
                        width: $(this)
                            .parents()
                            .attr("data-percent") + "%"
                    },
                    1000,
                    "linear",
                    function () {
                        return $(this).css({
                            "transition-duration": ".5s"
                        });
                    }
                );
        });

    $(".skills-soft li")
        .find("svg")
        .each(function (i) {
            var c, cbar, circle, percent, r;
            circle = $(this).children(".cbar");
            r = circle.attr("r");
            c = Math.PI * (r * 2);
            percent = $(this)
                .parent()
                .data("percent");
            cbar = (100 - percent) / 100 * c;
            circle.css({
                "stroke-dashoffset": c,
                "stroke-dasharray": c
            });
            circle.delay(i * 150).animate({
                    strokeDashoffset: cbar
                },
                1000,
                "linear",
                function () {
                    return circle.css({
                        "transition-duration": ".3s"
                    });
                }
            );
            $(this)
                .siblings("small")
                .prop("Counter", 0)
                .delay(i * 150)
                .animate({
                    Counter: percent
                }, {
                    duration: 1000,
                    step: function (now) {
                        return $(this).text(Math.ceil(now) + "%");
                    }
                });
        });
}.call(this));
```

Comment: How do you know there is an error?

Comment: I know there is an error/ the code isn't doing what I intend to do because i want to fill up the skill bars based on the percentage I put in it but instead it just fills up the whole circle and fills up nothing in the skills bar. I have also put an image link in the question above for your reference!!

Comment: there are still few things missing to run in on my pc... (leading lines of js, css)
please try to create an example of behavior on codepen.io or somewhere else, where we can test and fix ;)

Comment: hey I used an open source on codepen.io for this which can be found here : https://codepen.io/astronaomical/pen/KexYgb